# Python: Hangman Game, Not revealing letters in correct place

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm making a Hangman Game in Python for GCSE Computing task and all I've got to do is make sure that when someone types in the correct letter it will place it in the correct place in the word.
Code is as below:

```
def guess_part(word):
    lives = 6
    LetterCount = 0
    LetterMask = ""
    for x in range(len(word)): #run for loop for the amount of the length of word
        LetterMask = LetterMask + "*"
    print LetterMask
    while lives != 0 and LetterMask.find("*")!=-1: #while lives are not 0 and the amount of asterisks are not -1
        LetterGuess = raw_input("Enter a letter to guess?")
        LetterCount = 0
        for char in word:
            LetterCount = LetterCount + 1
        if LetterGuess not in word:
            lives = lives - 1
        else:
            if LetterGuess in word and lives != 0:
                print "Good Guess."
                LetterMask = list(LetterMask)
                LetterMask[LetterCount-1] = LetterGuess
                LetterMask = "".join(LetterMask)
                print LetterMask
            else:
                print "Incorrect."
    if lives == 0:
        print "You have ran out of lives, your word was: ", word
    else:
        print "You have correctly guess the word! Score: ", lives
        print "Play again?"
        again = raw_input("")
        again.lower()
        if again == "y":
            menu()
        elif again == "n":
            exit()
        else:
            exit()


def rand_word():
    from random import randrange
    random_words = ['extraordinary','happy','computer','python','screen','cheese','cabaret','caravan','bee','wasp','insect','mitosis','electronegativity','jumper','trousers']
    word = random_words[randrange(0, 15)] #pick a random number, and use this number as an index for the list, "random_words".
    guess_part(word) #call the function, "guess_part" with the parameter "word"

def user_word():
    print "All words will be changed to lowercase."
    print "Enter the word you would like to guess."
    print ""
    validation_input = False
    while validation_input == False: #while the validation input is not False, do below.
        word = raw_input("")
        if word.isalpha(): #If word contains only strings, no numbers or symbols, do below.
            word = word.lower() #set the string of variable, "word", to all lowercase letters.
            guess_part(word) #call the function, "guess_part" with the parameter, "word".
            validation_input = True #Break the while loop
        else:
            print "Word either contained numbers or symbols."

def menu():
    print "Hangman Game"
    print ""
    print "Ashley Collinge"
    print ""
    print "You will have 6 lives. Everytime you incorrectly guess a word, you will lose a life."
    print "The score at the end of the game, is used to determine the winner."
    print ""
    print "Would you like to use a randomly generated word, or input your own?"
    print "Enter 'R' for randomly generated word, or 'I' for your own input."
    decision_bool = False
    decision_length = False
    while decision_bool == False: #While decision_bool equals "False", do below.
        while decision_length == False: #While decision_length equals "False", do below.
            decision = raw_input("")
            if len(decision) == 1: #If the length of decision eqausl 1, do below.
                decision_length = True
                decision = decision.capitalize() #Capitalize the string value of decision.
                if decision == "R": #if the value of decision, eqauls "R".
                    print "You chose randomly generated word."
                    print ""
                    print "Forwarding..."
                    decision_bool = True
                    print ""
                    rand_word() #Call the function, rand_word()
                elif decision =="I": #If decision equals "I", do below.
                    print "You chose to input your own word."
                    print ""
                    print "Forwarding..."
                    decision_bool = True
                    print ""
                    user_word() #Call the function, user_word()
                else:
                    print "You entered an incorrect value for the question. Try again."
            else:
                print "You entered an incorrect value for the question. Try again."

menu()
```

Comment: The code is quite lengthy for a Stack Overflow question. You should try and find the part that misbehaves and focus on that.

Comment: Another matter is your comments. I understand this is probably one of the first programs you've ever written, but it's never too early to learn... Your comments are mostly trivial, in the sense they add nothing to the code. Placing a comment such "call the function guess_part with the parameter word" on the line guess_part(word) doesn't help anybody reading your code. When writing code, you should assume that people reading it will know the language.

Comment: Hi Ashley, and welcome to StackOverflow. What's your question? Can you shorten your code to the minimum number of lines necessary to reproduce your problem? A quick aside: You should think about what and  how you use comments. `while decision == False: #While decision equals "False", do below.` is not really useful. Comment *why* you do things, don't repeat what the code itself already says perfectly well.

Comment: @zmbq The only important part is the `guess_part()` func, as it is where the 'guessing' takes place. moreover the `if LetterGuess not in word` onwards

Comment: Ashley, take a look at the part of your code where you are iterating over the word... are you really finding at which index in the word the guessed character is located? You might want to look at the `find` and `index` methods of built-in strings.

Answer (score 0):

The code below might answer your question:
"All I've got to do is make sure that when someone types in
 the correct letter it will place it in the correct place in the word."
It does not validate inputs.
 *Tip*: if you validate, i suggest you take a look at the `re` module
Due to the `print` statements this code will not work if you're using python 3+:

```
from random import choice

def found(s , v):  
    # returns a list of indexes if v is in s
    # else it returns None
    return [i for i in range(len(s))if s[i] == v]

def guess_word(word, mask, lives):  

    # returns a 2 tuple : lettermask and the lives left
    # just like  'guess_part' but with 2 more para's  
    # to increase flexibility.
    # Beware !!! this function does not check the para's

    lettermask=list(len(word)* mask)
    livesleft ='You have {} lives left .\n'
    guess='Plz type a char a-z.\n>:'
    print word # just for checking
    while mask in lettermask:   
        if lives < 1: break
        print 'lettermask= '+ ''.join(lettermask)
        p = livesleft.format(lives)
        letterguess= raw_input(p + guess)
        print 'letterguess= '+ letterguess
        result = found( word, letterguess)
        if result:  
            print 'Good guess :) '
            for i in result :
                lettermask[i]=word[i]
        else:   
            print 'Wrong guess :( '
            lives-=1
    return lettermask,lives

random_words = ['extraordinary','happy','computer',
'python','screen','cheese','cabaret',
'caravan','bee','wasp','insect','mitosis',
'electronegativity','jumper','trousers']


word=choice (random_words)
# or word= raw_intput('pls type a word')
mask='*'
lives= 6
resultS,lives = guess_word(word, mask, lives)
if mask in resultS:  
   print 'Your result: {}'.format("".join(resultS))
   print 'You have failed,the word was: {}'.format(word)
else:
   print 'Congrats !!! Your score is: {}'.format(lives)
```